# How in the Blank is this happening?

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-entities, igrouping

Having to do alot of stuff to get IGrouping Working in MVC4 c#. Below are my queries

```
        var a = (from r in db.SomeProcedure(Id)
                       select new MyClass1
                       {
                           Id= r.Id,
                           Title = r.Title,
                           Name = r.Name,
                           Number = r.Number,
                           Product = r.Product,
                           OtherId = r,OtherId
                       }).ToList();
```

//The above returns 13 results as expected

```
        var b = a.GroupBy(x => x.Title ?? "unknown", c => new MyClass2
        {
            Title2 = c.Title,
            Id2 = c.Id,
            OtherId2 = c.OtherId,
            Number2 = c.Number
        });
```

//The above returns 2 as expected

```
        List<MyClass1> mClass1 = a;
        List<IGrouping<string,MyClass2>> mClass2 = b.ToList();
```

//The 2 above are the same as expected

Finally

```
        mPrivateClass1.Clear();
        mClass1 .ForEach(o => mPrivateClass1.Add(o));
```

//The above is the 13 as expected

```
        mPrivateClass2.Clear();
        mClass2 .ForEach(p => mPrivateClass2.AddRange(p));
```

//The above is returning 13 not 2 as expected.  I could not use Add(p) it gives Generic List<> .Add has some invalid arguments.

```
mPrivateClass1 is a:
 private List<MyClass1> mPrivateClass1 = new List<MyClass1>();

mPrivateClass2 is a:
 private List<MyClass2> mPrivateClass2 = new List<MyClass2>();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
mPrivateClass2.Clear();
mClass2 .ForEach(p => mPrivateClass2.AddRange(p));
//The above is returning 13 not 2 as expected.
```

Why would you like it to return 2 elements only? Because you're using `AddRange`, the entire grouping content is added into your `List`, and because `IGrouping<TKey, TElement>` implements `IEnumerable<TElement>` will all elements classified to that group, you're getting 13. That's the expected and desired value for your code.

To get only 2 elements in `mPrivateClass2` you'd have to decide, which element from the group should be added. For example, to add only the first item from each group use following:

```
mClass2.ForEach(p => mPrivateClass2.Add(p.First()));
```

You can add other methods, like `OrderBy`, to sort the `IGrouping` content before taking one item:

```
mClass2 .ForEach(p => mPrivateClass2.Add(p.OrderBy(x => Id).First()));
```

Comment: Want to put the Titles in a panel so the 2 titles first then the results from the first query as children

Answer (score 1):

This is because even though you have 2 groups in `mClass2`, you have 13 elements combined in the 2 groups, which you are adding as an `IEnumerable<MyClass2>` when you call `mPrivateClass2.AddRange`.

Which two elements from each of the groups of `MyClass2` would you expect to be added?